# Error found when uploading wordpress mikado theme

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using localhost with wamp server. But, when i am uploading the wordpress theme found these error code

```
Warning: include_once(C:\wamp\www\digitalatom/wp-content/themes/optimizewp/framework/modules/shortcodes/piecharts/piechartbasic/custom-styles/pie-chart-basic.php) 
[function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\wamp\www\digitalatom\wp-content\themes\optimizewp\framework\modules\shortcodes\piecharts\piechartbasic\load.php on line 4
```

Call Stake

```
Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0010 365336 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0 

2 0.0018 368976 require( 'C:\wamp\www\digitalatom\wp-blog-header.php' ) ..\index.php:17 
3 0.0029 393632 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\digitalatom\wp-load.php' ) ..\wp-blog-header.php:13 
4 0.0038 407208 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\digitalatom\wp-config.php' ) ..\wp-load.php:37 5 0.0065 545104 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\digitalatom\wp-settings.php' ) ..\wp-config.php:89
```

Comment: did you check the file structure?

Comment: @DainisAbols Yes Dainis. My wordpress theme includes following files Header.php,Sidebar.php,Footer.php and wp-admin, wp-content folder also. dont sure there would be problem there. please help

Comment: Pls see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload to a live server and its showing that error.
First thing you do is to double-check your wp-config.php.
you post the code so we can see